# FrontController in ZendFramework 1.11.3

Tags: php, zend-framework

What is purpose of this method in Bootstrap.php?

```
protected function _initFrontControler(){
    $this->bootstrap('FrontController');
    $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();

    $frontController->throwExceptions(true);
    $frontController->returnResponse(true); 

    try { 
        $response = $frontController->dispatch();
        if($response->isException()) { 
            throw new Exception; 
        } 
        $response->sendResponse();
    } catch (Exception $e) { 
        print $e->getMessage(); 
    }
}
```

I know that it can handle errors but then layouts for example doesn't work. What is complete implementation of this method to behave identically like default (or without this method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You bootstrap layout too, maybe in separate resource initialization function, e.g.:

```
protected function _initViewSetting(){
 $this->bootstrap('layout');
 $this->bootstrap('view');

 ...
}
```

Or you can do that in config file (ini/xml) and resource will load automatically. Actually, if you look deeper into ZF code, you'll see that FrontController is already loaded automatically.So instead of `$this->bootstrap('FrontController')`, you could use `$this->getResource('FronController')`

Personally, I wouldn't use the code you supplied. It just uses FrontController and dispatches the request, and takes care of exception handling. If that is in bootstrap, calling dispatch() directly is not very wise to do. Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Front-controller config - throw exceptions, etc - is typically done via `configs/application.ini`. If you are using `Zend_Application`, then calling `$application->run()` in your `public/index.php` file should invoke the dispatching. Like @usoban, I wouldn't put all this into `Bootstrap`.

Comment: Exactly. And after all, exception handling is done quite good with basic ZF implemetation. If additional functionality is needed, it's probably the best practice to modify ErrorHandler plugin.